# ¿Cómo extraer un subdocumento de una consulta en MongoDB con Python (Pymongo)?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

espero se encuentren bien. Trabajando en unas consultas a una base de datos en MongoDB con Python, específicamente con la librería PyMongo, me encuentro con el problema de extraer el valor de un SubDocumento para usarlo posteriormente en algunas funciones, ¿Cómo puedo extraer dicho valor y guardarlo en una variable? A continuación un poco del código utilizado (por cuestiones laborales no pondré los datos de la base de datos):

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient("mongodb://IP:Port/DataBase",
username="",password="")

db = client["DataBase"]
mycol = db["Colección"]


cursor = list(mycol.find({'nombre':'CURP','validaciones.longitud':18},{'_id':0}))
print(cursor)
```

Output:

```
[{'validaciones':{'longitud':18}}]
```

Me interesa extraer **Longitud:18** para guardar el valor en una variable y después utilizarlo en otras funciones, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo. Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos a todos.

Comment: `cursor[0]['validaciones']['longitud']`

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias! lo acabo de probar y funcionó, te lo agradezco mucho, buen día!